# How to give depth in nutch 2.3 crawl

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

In v2.2.1 there is a [nutch crawl](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch_crawl) command in which you can give depth to crawl

> bin/nutch crawl  [-solr ] [-dir d] [-threads n]
>   [-depth i] [-topN N]

How to do the same for nutch v2.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the script is not updated, I think the script there is relevant for Nutch 1.4.

You can always check Nutch formal repository at [github](https://github.com/apache/nutch), of course make sure that you're looking at the right branch.

Anyway, Nutch 2.X crawl script is as follows (and you can see the 2.3 source [here](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/branch-2.3/src/bin/crawl)):

```
crawl <seedDir> <crawlId> <solrURL> <numberOfRounds>
```

Where *seedDir* is the directory where your seed urls' files are, *crawlId* is a name you wish to call your crawl job, *solrURL* is self-explantory and *numberOfRounds* is what you are looking for.

Notice however that the script also has parameters that you can change (within the script), like the number of fetched pages per level (i.e. the breadth of crawl).

Answer (score 0):

it's in the nutch-default.xml in the conf folder